# Is there a way to intercept UIWebView dataDetectorType action sheets?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Is anyone aware of a way to override the default behavior of the links created in UIWebViews dataDetectorTypes? They cause a system action sheet to pop up, and don't appear to use any of the application-level calls such as UIApplication openURL, or the UIWebViewDelegate methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spoke with the Apple engineers in the WWDC labs and was told there are currently no hooks to do this. We ended up running NSDataDetectors manually on the html body text and inserting our own custom anchor tags, then detecting those in the webViewWillLoad... delegate message.